# Find the transition probability matrix. Check my answer.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

A coin is tossed continuously until 2 heads or 2 tails appear respectively.  Let the result of first toss is tail. The game is over when we get 2 heads respectively.

Determine the transition probability matrix.

Check my answer is correct or not.

Let $X_n$ denote the number of tail that appear.
Let the state $S=\{0,1,2\}$.

So, the transition probability matrix is 
$$P=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&\dfrac{1}{2}&\dfrac{1}{2}\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $a_{i,j}$ element in matrix describes the probability of transition from state $i$ to $j$. Your matrix describes process in which '$0$' is absorbing state (which is obviously not true).

If the matrix shall describe number of consecutive tails (and the two tails is absorbing state) then the matrix is as follows: 
$$P=
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{1}{2}&\dfrac{1}{2}&0\\
\dfrac{1}{2}&0&\dfrac{1}{2}\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Why $P_{10}=\dfrac{1}{2}$? I think if we have first toss is tail then it is imposibble the number of tail next toss is $0$.

Comment: Rows/columns of your matrix are states?

Comment: Yes. It is state.

Comment: Your matrix shall describe number of consecutive tails (which corresponds to your game), or number of tails in general?

Comment: number of consecutive tails

Comment: Then if you throw tails at first and after that you throw heads then how much consecutive tails will you have after that throw? $0$ as the last throw was heads.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Now I understand what you mean. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case you need to have 4 states: state 2 tails, state tail, state head and state 2 heads which I will call states 1,2,3 and 4 respectively.

$$P=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
\dfrac{1}{2}&0&\dfrac{1}{2}&0\\
0&\dfrac{1}{2}&0&\dfrac{1}{2}\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

If I understand you correctly you keep playing until you get either two heads or two tails. Then, states 1 and 4 are absorbing states.

Then when you are in state 2 (got a tail) then you can jump after the coin flip to either state 1 (two tail flips) or state 3 (one head).

If you start with a tail then your initial state probability vector $\pi$ would be

$$\pi=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$